# Bash programming: find lines that matches

Tags: regex, bash

cchair: matches lines that have at least two c’s (consecutive or nonconsecutive) followed by 'hair', not necessarily immediately after the second c

i tried this: 'c*hair' but c's don't necessarily have to be consecutive

Comment: Does .*c.*c.*hair work for you?

Comment: You probably just want `c.*chair`. It will match `c.rf34§=+chair`, for example.

Comment: The 'hair' part doesn't have to follow immidiately after the c part, so your solution would fail in c.rf34$=+c+hair

Comment: At any rate, `*` must be changed to `.*`, that is all there is to it in regex.